# jQuery resizable on iPad and IE 8

Tags: jquery, ipad, internet-explorer-8, jquery-ui-resizable

I have a div that I have successfully made resizable horizontally in all browsers exept IE 8 and any browser on the iPad. Anyone know if there are anything special I can do to get a resizable div to work in these browsers?

I am using the default jqueryui css theme and setting the div resizble with the following jquery code...

```
$(".treeMenu").resizable({
     handles: 'e, w'

});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [jQuery Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) for iPad support. It's an easy way to get jQuery UI to work with iPad touch events.

After you include it you would then use the `resizable` event as normal.

Comment: I had a resizable handler that wouldn't work on pads and smartphones, now it works like a charm! Thanks a lot.